# How to make empty parts of aerial imagery transparent?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have this problem in QGIS which is very similar to this one: [Making empty parts of aerial imagery transparent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133945/making-empty-parts-of-aerial-imagery-transparent)

I want to connect all these different rasters, so that they form one big aerial image. I already found how to remove the big white borders, so everything looks much better. However, there still remain smaller dots at the borders of the different rasters. Anyone knows how to remove these?

First image:
[image: http://i66.tinypic.com/2ijkuj4.jpg]

Second image: 
[image]

Comment: Do you know values of remainder pixels? You can use Transparency tab creating a range for transparent pixels

Comment: I started 'adding values from display', but if I have to do this whole process for every single raster, then it will take me forever! There has to be an easier way to fix this? [edit] http://i64.tinypic.com/azbe6o.jpg

Comment: Did you know how to use Python inside QGIS (pyqgis)... You can create a list of three-value range creating a master file to set transparency for the rest of your raster layers. The master file could be a .txt with red, green, blue and transparency values with all combination of the range values (from 249 to 254 or something like this)

Comment: In layer properties,  style manager you can choose blending mode as multiplay.

Comment: @aldo_tapia I don't have any experience with Python, so I don't know how to do this properly. Maybe you can give me some instructions?

Comment: @nagib The layers that I'm talking about are raster layers, not vector layers. This means that I can't run the blending mode.

Comment: Blending mode exists for raster, see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Raster blending mode-> multiply

[image]

[image]

[image]